# R, Removing duplicate along with the original value

Tags: r

I'm trying to use R to delete all the duplicate values without keeping the original value.

For example I've the following list

```
 1. Car 
 2. Car
 3. Food
```

Unique function will remove the the duplicate and will keep the original.

```
 1. Car 
 2. Food
```

I need to to remove all the duplicate values and to get only the value that occurred once.

```
1. Food
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Could try `x <- c("Car", "Car", "Food") ; x[!(duplicated(x) | duplicated(x, fromLast = TRUE))]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use

```
df1[!(duplicated(df1$col)|duplicated(df1$col, fromLast=TRUE)),, drop=FALSE]
#   col
#3. Food
```